# CREATE IDENTIFIER ----Insert 2 forms data into one table using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have two forms : student.html and faculty.html and I want to store their data into one table called `TEACHING_AWARD_NOMINATIONS`

I use the same php file for both of them. Below is my code:

```
$srr = array_map('mysql_escape_string', $_REQUEST);

if ($srr['NOMINATIONTYPE'] == 'STUDENT')
    $fields = Array('TYPE','NAME', 'EMAIL', 'NOMINEE', 'DEPT', 'COURSE', 'YEARTERM', 'REQUIRED_FOR_MAJOR', 'MAJOR_LEARNING_OBJECTIVES', 'WHAT_EXTENT_INSTRUCTOR_HELP', 'RANK', 'RANK_COMMENT','EVIDENCE','EFFECTION','CONTRIBUTION', 'TEXTBOX_1', 'TEXTBOX_2', 'TEXTBOX_3', 'TEXTBOX_4', 'TEXTBOX_5');
else if ($srr['NOMINATIONTYPE'] == 'FACULTY')
    $fields = Array('TYPE','NAME', 'EMAIL', 'NOMINEE', 'DEPT', 'COURSE', 'YEARTERM', 'REQUIRED_FOR_MAJOR', 'MAJOR_LEARNING_OBJECTIVES', 'WHAT_EXTENT_INSTRUCTOR_HELP', 'RANK', 'RANK_COMMENT','EVIDENCE','EFFECTION','CONTRIBUTION', 'TEXTBOX_1', 'TEXTBOX_2', 'TEXTBOX_3', 'TEXTBOX_4', 'TEXTBOX_5');
else die('error: no nomination type');


foreach ($fields as $f)
    $$f = $srr[$f];

$qry = "INSERT INTO TEACHING_AWARD_NOMINATIONS (";
    foreach ($fields as $f) $qry .= $f . ", ";
    $qry = substr($qry, 0, -2);
    $qry .= ") VALUES (";
    foreach ($fields as $f) $qry .= "'" . $$f . "', ";
    $qry = substr($qry, 0, -2);
    $qry .= ")";

$result = mysql_query($qry) or die('An error ocurred: '.mysql_error());

echo 'Success! Thank you for submitting your nomination.';
```

It stores the data perfectly except the `'TYPE'` column in the table

below are the code in each html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="NOMINATIONTYPE" value="FACULTY" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="Reset" />


<input type="hidden" name="NOMINATIONTYPE" value="STUDENT" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="Reset" />
```

How can I create a identifier for the table? I want the data submitted from student form shows type: student in the table and data submitted from faculty form shows type: faculty in the table .

Please help ~~~

Comment: What do you mean when you say it "doesn't work"?  What goes wrong?  What error are you getting?  And have you tried displaying the SQL statement that you're generating, instead of just running it?  It might be easier to see your error that way.

Comment: Also - your code looks a bit dangerous, from the point of view of SQL injection attacks.  I hope you're not running this on a server that's exposed to the Internet.

Comment: can you double check foreach ($fields as $f) $qry .= "'" . $$f . "', "; why you have 2 $ ? and you can echo the query and see what it returns, it will help to find the issue.

Comment: echo $qry ; put this printed output in your question and try this printed output to run in your mysql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because inside your first `foreach`, you're looking for `$srr['TYPE']`, which presumably doesn't exist.  The simple solution would be to rename your hidden elements to `TYPE` instead of `NOMINATIONTYPE`.  Alternatively, you could do some logic within the `foreach` such that `if($f == 'TYPE'){$ff = $srr['NOMINATIONTYPE'];} else{$$f = $srr[$f];}`